# Do other identification methods of android apps exist?

Tags: android, code-signing-certificate

I'm wondering: Besides the apk signing via a key. Is there some way that Google tracks an app?

I mean, they could include informations like hardware configuration and other computer related stuff into an apk in order to uniquely fingerprint an app. As a result, although an app has been signed by different keys they are still able to determine which apps belong together?

Do they do something like that when you create an apk?

Answer (score 0):

It's far simpler than that - when you upload an app to the Play Store, you do so using an account, so Google simply groups together the apps that are owned by the same account (ie that of the publisher, which may not be that of the developer).

These don't have to be signed by the same key - in fact in general outside of the apps that are preinstalled on a device (which all share the system key), most apps from a publisher have their own individual keys.  That way an app can be transferred to a new publisher with minimal disruption to existing users.

Comment: So, having two apps with signed by two different keys and under two separtate developer accounts (gmail accounts). In that case Google is not able to infer a connection between both apps?